# How to use FallbackFuture to handle TimeoutException?

Tags: java, guava

I have my task and fallback for it:

```
ListenableFuture<T> listenableAsyncTask = executorService.submit(asyncTaskCallable);
ListenableFuture<T> listenableFallbackTask = executorService.submit(fallBackTaskCallable);
```

From them, I form a fail tolerant ListenableFuture:

```
ListenableFuture<T> failTolerantListenableFuture = Futures.withFallback(listenableAsyncTask, new FutureFallback<T>() {
                @Override
                public ListenableFuture<T> create(Throwable t) throws Exception {
                    return listenableFallbackTask;
                }
            });
```

And I have a list of fail tolerant futures:

```
List<ListenableFuture<T>> listenableFutures = ...;
```

It's time to get the result, in a certain amount of time:

```
result = Futures.allAsList(listenableFutures).get(50,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

At this point, I expect that if a task failed to finish within 50ms, the return output will be handled by the fallBackTask, which is a lightweight one.

But not as I planed, I got the following exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for task.
```

Which causes me losing all results from other succeed tasks. It seems that the fallback didn't work in this case for me. Or I misunderstood the concept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to distinguish between "the `Future` fails" and "the call to `Future.get` fails."

- "The `Future` fails" if the task you submitted throws an exception. (For purposes of `withFallback`, we also consider cancellation to be a failure. That's not relevant here, though, and the behavior may change someday.)
- "The call to `Future.get` fails" if *any* of the following happen:

  - the `Future` fails
  - the call times out
  - the call is interrupted

`withFallback` handles only the case in which the `Future` fails, without handling cases of timeout or interruption.

If your goal is to retrieve all the primary results that are done within 50 milliseconds, with all other cases falling back to the secondary results, you can try something like this, which uses `withTimeout` to automatically fail the `Future` after a given timeout:

```
List<ListenableFuture<T>> originalFutures = ...;
List<ListenableFuture<T>> defaultAfterTimeoutFutures = new ArrayList<>();
for (ListenableFuture<T> f : originalFutures) {
  f = Futures.withTimeout(f, 50, MILLISECONDS, executor);
  f = Futures.withFallback(f, ...);
  defaultAfterTimeoutFutures.add(f);
}
result = Futures.allAsList(defaultAfterTimeoutFutures).get();
```

But note that that last `get` call may wait longer than 50 milliseconds: If a primary `Future` fails, then the `get` call must wait until its fallback is done. If you don't want to wait for the fallbacks, then you will need to wrap them with `withTimeout`, as well. And if you do wrap them, then they will fail after the timeout, at which point `allAsList` will also fail. If you don't want that, then you'll need to either use `successfulAsList` (instead of `allAsList`) or wrap the wrappers with `withFallback` again, this time with a value that is always available immediately.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the clear explanation on WithFallback wrapping :)